# How do I include a Django app in my PYTHONPATH?

Tags: django, eclipse, django-models, django-forms

I want to be able to import things from applications in my project without referring to my project name.

My folder structure is like so; I have a project called djangoproject1, and inside I have a folder called apps, and then I have my individual apps in that folder.

djangoproject1, apps, and all my applications have an empty "__init__.py" file in them.

In my settings.py file I have the following code:

```
import os
import sys
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))
```

I've tried adding my apps to INSTALLED_APPS several ways:

'djangoproject1.apps.app1',
'djangoproject1.apps.app2',

or

'apps.app1',
'apps.app2',

or

'app1',
'app2',

but nothing works.  Whenever I try to do:

```
from app1 import *
```

I got an unresolved import error.  I'm using the latest versions of eclipse and django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I got it to work by adding the apps folder to the PYTHONPATH through eclipse under Project Properties.  Is this eclipse only though?  I'm not sure how this will work when I try and deploy the site.  What do you guys think?

Comment: Ah. That explains things. If you add to `settings.py` and do not execute `shell`, your `PYTHONPATH` does not change. If you want the app to be importable without using `shell` then you will have to add it to the _system variable_ `PYTHONPATH`. You'll can get away by adding apps through settings.py in production.

Comment: Ok thanks so, for now then, adding through Eclipse is fine for development, and as long as I leave that code in settings.py, when I deploy it, it should also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))` looks OK to me. Following this you only need to add `app1` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and everything *should* work. But apparently they are not working.

Try the following: 1. Print your `sys.path` and verify that your project's `app` directory is in the list. 2. Double check that your have an `__init__.py` inside your *`apps`* folder.

**Update**

OK. Now can you fire up Django shell and try importing again? If it fails, please post the stack trace here.

Comment: 1. 'C:\\Users\\jec23\\My Java Projects\\djangoproject1\\src\\djangoproject1\\apps'  This is the relevant sys.path entry.

2. Yup, thats there.

Answer (score 0):

You must include apps directory to PYTHONPATH. Be sure that in apps directory don't have __init__.py, because it become a package instead of "simple directory". Than, include in settings.py

```
app1, app2, app3
```

Use

```
from app1 import *
```